# Pointwise and uniform convergence sequence

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I posted similiar question an hour ago, so I just want to check, if I undestand it correctly for another problem.

I am supposed to determine if series of function $\left \{ n^{2}x^{n}\left ( 1-x \right ) \right \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ on interval $M\left [ 0,1 \right ]$is converging pointwise and uniform.

Pointwise:

Yes, it is, because $\lim_{n \to  \infty }( n^{2}x^{n}\left ( 1-x \right ))=0 $

Uniform:

$a_{n}=sup_{x \in \mathbb{R} }\left | n^{2}x^{n}\left ( 1-x \right )-0 \right |=\left |n^{2}x^{n}\left ( 1-x \right )  \right |$

Maximum of function is $x=\frac{n}{1+n}$ so:

$\lim_{n \to \infty }(n^{2}\left ( \frac{n}{1+n} \right )^{n}\left ( \frac{1}{1+n} \right ))= \infty$, therefore function does not converge uniform.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. You should have stated that the maximum of $x\mapsto n^2x^n(1-x)$ is *attained at* $\frac n{n+1}$. The maximum itself is $n\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^{n+1}$. The rest is fine.

Comment: Oh, okay thank you, because I was completely lost.. you really help me.

Comment: Also the $\sup$ is not over $\mathbb R.$